# consultas especificas en firebase con python, pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, flask, sql

Estoy usando `firebase` para mi `api` en `python`, pero estoy teniendo un inconveniente.

Tengo una colección de datos de una persona:
documento, nombres, apellidos, teléfono, dirección, etc..

Quiero hacer una consulta donde sólo obtenga los nombres y apellidos
de esta persona.

Comment: alberto, recuerda que el funcionamiento del sitio se basa en preguntas y respuestas concretas. Si tu pregunta es así de abierta, podrían cerrarla por basarse en supuestos, ya que la respuesta también podría ser demasiado abierta. Te sugiero que sigas el [tour] si es que no lo has hecho aún.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera consultas datos en firebase con python

```
db.child('condominios').order_by_child('codAdministrador').equal_to(codAdministrador).get().val()
```

Estos tutoriales te pueden ayudar más

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs
https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database

y si te da un error de indexOn esta es la solución 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968413/error-index-not-defined-add-indexon